# How can i replace a electret mic input with headphone output as input

Tags: audio, gsm, sim900, electret

I'm using a SIM800L GSM module for my project. In this module there is a electret mic input pin but I want to give audio to this module from headphone output from a mobile (There is no line in pin available). If I directly input from headphone out the module make too much noise. 
Now what is the best idea to implement this?

Here is module instruction diagram:

[image: SIM800L mic integration]

[image: Mic input/Audio output characteristics]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Not sure what you are asking of us. To use a speaker as a microphone? Using a speaker as a mic will overload the mic input. The mic input may have a small bias voltage as well.

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/239708/headphone-out-to-microphone-in-for-mobile-phones Not a dupe but likely does solve it.

Comment: Decrease the volume on the source and turn it up on the target device.  This sounds like it could just be typical behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did this, so I can answer by experience.
I have a SIM800L module that's answering calls via a PHP script on a Raspberry Pi 3, and I wanted to send PicoTTS voice on the line using the AUX jack audio output.
I followed [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aovtGu_pG4w) using "mostly" the correct values components. I got the resistances pretty much right by playing with 4.7k and 1k resistors, and just the capacitor is shooting up with 47uF instead of 1uF.

I only connected the left side of the jack output leaving the other lead unconnected, the level I get on the phone is alright, the voice quality is alright, I just get some vibrating noise as soon as the phonecall is connected, which disappears slowly and after a while of mostly clean audio comes back, as if a big fly was briefly flying by and then going away again.
But still, I can testify it works, an the noise is OK with me anyway.

[image: Line level converter]

Answer (score 0):

The 90mW into 32 ohms from the headphones output of your mobile is 1.7V (RMS?).
The output of your voice from an electret mic (conversation level at a distance of 10cm) is only 10mV. So you must attenuate the headphones signal 1.7V/10mV= to 1/170.

90mW into 32 ohm headphones is VERY loud. 100mV from an electret mic is also VERY loud. Then attenuate to 1.7V/100mV= 1/17th.

Comment: This would be a lot more useful as an answer if you explained *how* to do that.  If the asker knew how to design an attenuator they probably would not have asked the question.